# Resteasy @QueryParam parsing

Tags: java, rest, curl, resteasy

I have a rest endpoint as below. pid is UUID which I'm parsing using UUID.fromString(pid);

```
@GET
    @Path("/")
    public Response process(@Context HttpServletRequest req,
                               @QueryParam("p") String pid,
                               @DefaultValue("3") @QueryParam("a") String active,
                               @DefaultValue("3") @QueryParam("c") String closed,
                               @CookieParam("X") String cookie) {
//my stuff
}
```

This is not setting 'p' and 'X' when I run jetty and curl using

```
curl localhost:9090/rest/accounts?p=<uuid>&c=4&a=5 -b "X=1212;"
```

response is  `-b: command not found`

it works when I move cookie part to front

curl -b "X=1212;" localhost:9090/rest/accounts?p=&c=4&a=5

but 'c' and 'a' are always 3 (default). 
Is there something wrong with the way I'm using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell probably interpreted **&**, try:

```
curl -b "X=1212;" "localhost:9090/rest/accounts?p=&c=4&a=5"
```

If you want to see detail information about request and response use:

```
curl -v -b "X=1212;" "localhost:9090/rest/accounts?p=&c=4&a=5"
```